# Update chart based on dropdown selection - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I need to update the chart based on dropdown change.
i dont know how to do in javascript or jquery.

i have created fiddle to explain my situation

**http://jsfiddle.net/sELst/25/**

this is the html

```
<select id="chartType">
<option>bar chart</option>
<option>area chart</option>
<option>line chart</option>
<option>spline chart</option>
</select>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

JS

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        rows: [
            ['data4', 'data2', 'data3'],
            [90, 120, 300],
            [40, 160, 240],
            [50, 200, 290],
            [120, 160, 230],
            [80, 130, 300],
            [90, 220, 320]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    }
});
```

this is my customisation , trying

```
var currentChart = 0;
var charts = [{
    type: 'line',
    data: 'data4'
}, {
    type: 'area',
    data: 'data2'
}, {
    type: 'spline',
    data: 'data3'
}];

$(function () {
    $("#chartType").change(function (evt) {
        var chartSelection = $("#chartType").val();
        $('#chart').hide().filter(charts + chartSelection).show();
    });
});
```

**in detail explanation**

i am working on c3.js charts

in c3, it has 4 kinds of charts

1. bar chart
2. area chart
3. spline chart
4. line chart

whenever user changes the dropdown or select the other charts i need to update the chart.

C3 library link

**http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html**

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90b2y2sk/)**

When working with dropdowns you should give each option a value attribute, this is the value that `.val()` will later return for us and the same we'll use to specify the chart type we want.

```
<select id="chartType">
  <option value="bar">bar chart</option>
  <option value="area">area chart</option>
  <option value="line">line chart</option>
  <option value="spline">spline chart</option>
</select>
```

With our `EventListener` we then listen for a selection in the dropdown and when something is selected we regenerate the chart in that type.

```
$("#chartType").change(function (evt) {
    var chartSelection = $("#chartType").val();
    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            rows: data,
            type: chartSelection
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @ Faheem - please help me on this if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827273/update-array-values-to-chart-based-on-timeframe-javascript